# how to show font on hovering the mouse over image

Tags: html, css

i want to show the span tag content only when someone hover the mouse over it I have no idea to do it I trie onmouseover in the same span tag but I did not work any idea or suggestion will be helpful

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="python" id="py"> <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331553/python-package-index.svg" alt="" id="py" width='50px'><span id="py">Python</span>
```

what I want to do is when some person is hovering over or over the check box input than span  content appear and tell user the name of image in right hand side that's why I connected I give all of them same id it can be wrong

Comment: You are using multiple similar IDs and have not wrapped your content in a div to better organize the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
  #py-text {
        display: none;

    }

    .wrapper:hover #py-text {
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="checkbox" name="python" id="py-checkbox">
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331553/python-package-index.svg" alt="" id="py-img"                 width='50px'>
            <span id="py-text">Python</span>
 </div>
```